# ERROR: Slack notification failed. See Jenkins logs for details. After Recent Update

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, slack

I updated to the latest version of the plugin last week, and ever since then, no notifications are going through to our slack channel.

Anyone else having this issue?

Here is the error I am seeing in my job log.

```
Slack Send Pipeline step running, values are - baseUrl: <empty>, teamDomain: ourdomain, channel: #product_engineering, color: #00FF00, botUser: false, tokenCredentialId: token
ERROR: Slack notification failed. See Jenkins logs for details.
```

This is how we send -- this was working until two days ago.

```
slackSend color: "good", message: "Job: ${params.jobName} with buildnumber ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} was successful"
```